# SQL Server Agent Job step Processing Power BI Service Model through SSIS package (Analysis Services Processing Task) not working

Tags: sql-server, ssis, powerbi, xmla

I want to use a SQL Server Agent job on SQL Server 2017 (on premise) to update an XMLA Power BI dataset.

In order to do so, I have created an SSIS package with an Analysis Services Processing Task where I connect to the Power BI api: `Data Source=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/....`

[image]

When I run it through Visual Studio, it works like a charm, no issues.
I have deployed it as a package to Integrations Services Catalog on SQL Server, but when I try to run it there, with my username (email format) and same password as in Visual Studio, I the error below in the job output.

"[image]"

Has anyone managed to process a Power BI Premium dataset through XMLA using SQL Server Job Agent Job Step?